# How did the guys get weapons and gadgets in the sewer?

Tags: plot-explanation, tmnt-2014

In the  [Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1291150/)  movie, April rescued the turtles and the rat (Splinter) and left them in sewer. When they grew up, they had access to gadgets like skateboards, monitors and weapons like samurai swords and nunchuks. Splinter didn't allow the turtles to go outside because they're not ready, so how did they manage to get all those gadgets, weapons and even pizza?

Since the TMNT exists since the 80's I'm guessing it was explained in one of the comics or cartoon shows or is it just a plot hole?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In past continuities the Turtles have been scavengers. They find whatever they need from the trash that winds up in their sewer (how realistic *that* is, is another matter entirely). Usually it's Donatello who has the skill to salvage and fix whatever equipment/weapons they find.

Another possibility, is Splinter himself. While he has forbidden the Turtles from leaving the sewers there's nothing preventing *him* from leaving. Though I can't recall any continuity showing us that this did indeed happen, I'm fairly certain it did.

As for pizza, in the first live action TMNT movie we see them getting pizzas delivered to a manhole in a dark alley.